# Set_value() Array fields select option Codeigniter not working

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-3

I trying to create dynamic server side select input, after i submit, the set_value('nilai[]') not showing any value.

Here's my Controller below:

```
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nilai[]', 'Nilai Pantuhir', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
      $this->load->view('pantuhir/pantuhir_form');
    } else {
      $list_pantuhir = $this->input->post('nilai');

      foreach ($list_pantuhir as $key => $value) {
        echo $value."<br />";
      }
    }
```

Here's my view below :

```
    <div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('nilai[]')){echo 'has-error';} ?>">
      <select class="form-control" name="nilai[]">
        <option value="">- Choose-</option>
        <option value="<?php echo $rowPerson['intUserId'].'-'.'A';?>" <?php if(set_value('nilai[]') == $rowPerson['intUserId'].'-'.'A') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>A</option>
        <option value="<?php echo $rowPerson['intUserId'].'-'.'B';?>" <?php if(set_value('nilai[]') == $rowPerson['intUserId'].'-'.'B') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>B</option>
     </select>
     <?php echo form_error('nilai[]'); ?>
    </div>
```

I want to show set_value and get selected in option field if validation not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Use `set_select` instead of `set_value`. If you use a  menu, this function permits you to display the menu item that was selected, after the form validation throws any error*

It should be like this :

```
<div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('nilai[]')){echo 'has-error';} ?>">
    <select name="nilai[]" >
      <option value="" >---Choose----</option>
      <option 
              value="<?=$rowPerson['intUserId'].'-A';?>" 
              <?=set_select('nilai[]', $rowPerson['intUserId'].'-A');?>
      >A</option>
      <option 
              value="<?php echo $rowPerson['intUserId'].'-B';?>" 
              <?=set_select('nilai[]', $rowPerson['intUserId'].'-B');?> 
      >B</option>
    </select>
<?php echo form_error('nilai[]'); ?>
</div>
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#set_select

Comment: Can we add form_error only on select that error? because when one select error, all select input also show error too.

Comment: form_error identifies error with the name attributes so  select with different name will work for you , and just remove the last form_error from your form `<?php echo form_error('nilai[]'); ?>` and use error class to show the error as u do at the top

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in the view

```
<div class="form-group <?php if(form_error('nilai[]')){echo 'has-error';} ?>">
  <select class="form-control" name="nilai[]">
    <option value="">- Choose-</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $rowPerson['intUserId'].'-'.'A';?>" <?php if(set_value('nilai[]',rowPerson['intUserId'].'-'.'A') == $rowPerson['intUserId'].'-'.'A') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>A</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $rowPerson['intUserId'].'-'.'B';?>" <?php if(set_value('nilai[]',$rowPerson['intUserId'].'-'.'B') == $rowPerson['intUserId'].'-'.'B') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>B</option>
 </select>
 <?php echo form_error('nilai[]'); ?>
</div>
```